# Using decorators for try/except management

Tags: python, exception, python-decorators

I have a program with some low-level hardware components, which may fail(not initialized, timeout, comm issues, invalid commands etc.). They live in a server, which receives requests from a webclient.

So my idea is to have custom exceptions to capture what may fail in which drive - so that I can in some cases take remediation actions (e.g. try to reset the adapter if it's a comm problem etc.), or bubble up the errors in the cases where I can't do anything low-level, perhaps so that the server can return a generic error message to the webclient.

For instance:

```
class DriveException(Exception):
    """ Raised when we have a drive-specific problem """
    def __init__(self, message, drive=None, *args):
        self.message = message
        self.drive = drive
        super().__init__(message, drive, *args)
```

But then that drive may have had a problem because, say, the ethernet connexion didn't respond:

```
class EthernetCommException(Exception):
    """ Raised when ethernet calls failed  """
```

In the code, I can ensure my exceptions bubble up this way:

```
   # ... some code .... 
   try:
        self.init_controllers()         # ethernet cx failed, or key error etc.
    except Exception as ex:
        raise DriveException(ex) from ex
   # .... more code....
```

I have a high-level try/except in the server to ensure it keeps responding to requests & doesn't crash in case of a low-level component not responding. That mechanic works fine.

However, I have many different drives. I'd rather avoid putting lots of try/except everywhere in my code. My current idea is to do something like:

```
def koll_exception(func):
    """ Raises a drive exception if needed """
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_exception(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return value
        except Exception as ex:
            raise DriveException(ex, drive=DriveEnum.KOLLMORGAN) from ex
    return wrapper_exception
```

So that I can just dO:

```
@koll_exception
def risky_call_to_kolldrive():
    #doing stuff & raising a drive exception if anything goes wrong


# then anywhere in the code
foo = risky_call_to_kolldrive()
```

My prototype seems to work fine with the decorator. However I've search a bit about using to approach to try/except and was somewhat surprise not to find much about it. Is there a good reason why people don't do that I'm not seeing? Other than they usually just wrap everything in a high-level try/catch & don't bother much more with it?

Comment: Maybe you've simplified this too much, but the only difference between the original exception and the `DriveException` you raise in its place is a constant that's independent of any context surrounding the original exception. You haven't added any information that you couldn't just assume came with the original.

Comment: My idea was that the exception class would mostly be what tells me what happened & what the context is. I raise it from ex so that if, say, I at some point have an EthernetException while using, say, FooDrive it may or not be handled the same than it will be with, say, BarDrive, or I may not want/need the same infos in each cases...

Comment: But what does `drive=DriveEnum.KOLLMORGAN` tell you if *every* exception is tagged with that same value? Is the logic of `drive_exception` more complicated so that different values can be supplied, or do you envision different versions of the function that hard-code a different value for the `drive` argument?

Comment: Oups - mistake on my part, will correct. It does indeed not make much sense as it is.

Comment: Basically - I have a bunch of different drives. Just a generic class for drives in general is probably fine for now, but I'd still want to know which one at least. So I would have a different decorator for each drive types. Perhaps eventually I will subclass the DriveException clas for each... in which case the decorator would allow me to just do it in one place... instead of in each individual try/excpet....

Comment: Even then, the custom exception isn't interesting, because the very fact that you have decorated a function with `koll_exception` means that every exception it might raise came from `KOLLMORGAN`. If you are catching the exception at a level where you aren't sure which function ultimately raised the exception, then the information is useful, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203704/discussion-between-francky-v-and-chepner).